# How to submit a prompt inside a .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, prompt

I have a prompt in my script.js file that takes an input (username) and stores it in an array, and should then send the array to the server.

I am wondering how, specifically, to get the "`prompt.submit`" part to work, as it currently states, "prompt.submit is not a function" in the console. - I know this isn't correct, but I'm not sure how else to do this.

```
var socket = io();

var items = [];
var user = user;
if (!user) {
  user = prompt('Please choose a username:');
  items.push(user);
  if (!user) {
    alert('Your name has been set to "Anonymous"');
  } else {
      alert('Your name has been set to "'+ user +'"');
  } 
}
console.log(items);

$(function (e) {
    prompt.submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
      socket.emit(items);
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Please note, I am basing the above code on the following working code, which takes an input from a form in the HTML file and sends it to the server:

```
 $(function () {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
  });
```

How can I recreate the `$('form').submit` for the prompt in this .js file?

Comment: are u running this in browser?

Comment: Yes, it's a node.js system using socket.io and express.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to explicitly call prompt.submit since there is no such method. Using prompt will freeze your code execution from where it is called and will continue on clicking ok, which while eventually get its value as well

```js
$("document").ready(function () {
  //var socket = io();

var items = [];
var user = prompt('Please choose a username:');
  
  if (!user || user ==="") {
    alert('Your name has been set to "Anonymous"');
    items.push("Anonymous")
  } else {
    items.push(user);
      alert('Your name has been set to "'+ user +'"');
  }


  sendItems(...items)


function sendItems(items) {
  console.log(items)
  //socket.emit('chat message',items);
  return false;
}
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```